# TypeScript: How to edit tsconfig.json to allow add keys to existing object?

Tags: typescript

I want the following working by default:

```
let j = {a:1};
j.b = 2;
```

I know there are some other workarounds, I just want to know if I can make it work by only editing `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: what's the point of typescript if you're not using it's type system? Either declare your variable as `any` or give it an actual type. Typescript will infer the type from it's initial declaration, and you can't really change that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> I know there are some other workarounds, I just want to know if I can make it work by only editing tsconfig.json?

#### Short Answer

There is no `tsconfig.json` option for that.

#### More Details

None of these `tsconfig.json` options exist:

- "allow adding additional properties to a type after defining that type",
- "widen object literal type inference to include keys added after its declaration",
- "infer object literal types as `Record<K,V>` types".

As a result, there is no `tsconfig.json` option that will allow this:

```
let j = { a: 1 };
j.b = 2;
```

That is because TypeScript infers the type of object literals at the time of assignment. As a result, your original code is the equivalent of this.

```
type J = { a: number };
let j: J = { a: 1 };
j.b = 2;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `type J = { [key: string]: number }` because `{ a: number }` only restricts to a single key `a`?

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie I'm trying to illustrate what the OP is asking TypeScript to allow with a `tsconfig.json` option.

Answer (score 1):

`tsconfig.json` does not have an option to make all objects to default to something like type `{[key: string]: any}`. Even if it did, TypeScript would probably still need to know what type your keys and values are.

As a suggestion, you should type `j` with the following:

```
let j: {[key: string]: number} = {a:1};
j.b = 2;
```